# css id not applied to inside elements

Tags: html, css

My css code:

```
#header
{
width:900px;
border:dashed 1px;
margin:5px;
padding:2px;
}
#header .fl_left
{
float:left;
display:block;
width:260px;
}
#header .fl_left h1
{
float:left;
background-color:#666633;
color:#0033CC;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-style:oblique;
}
```

My html code:

```
<body>
<div id="header"><div class="fl_left"> <h1>hello all</h1> </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the output 'hello all' outside header. My intention is to put h1 element text inside header.

Why the header id rule is not applied to my h1 element.

Comment: What is the goal of your code? Do you want your `h1` title to float in the header box? Also you declare some properties twice at different locations. So please explain more into detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#header` selector only applies to the header element iself, not its children, and there is nothing in the style that would be inherited by the children.

The reason that the text ends up outside the header is that the header only contains floating elements which don't take up space, so they don't affect the height of the header.

You can add `overflow: hidden` to the header to make it contain its children:

```css
#header {
    width:900px;
    border:dashed 1px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:2px;
    overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: I ve removed float:left from my #header .fl_left h1. Now i ve placed my float:left only in my fl_left class. And i tried with overflow:hidden in #header, but it doesnt work

Comment: @crazyvi: Then you probably have something else in your code that keeps ir from working. Here I took your code and added `overflow`: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/jkXFU/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#header` style declaration.

Also, does the `<h1>` element really need to be floated left considering its parent `.fl_left` is already floated? If it does, then `.fl_left` will need `overflow: hidden;` too.

Comment: I ve removed float:left from my #header .fl_left h1. Now i ve placed my float:left only in my fl_left class. And i tried with  overflow:hidden in #header, but it doesnt work.

Comment: It seems to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/nr4ZY/. Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `float` in your `h1` tag which is unbinding your text out of `h1`. If it is necessary to use `float` then go with [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aafter) selector.

Add this code to your CSS file (before adding go through the above link)

```
#header .fl_left h1
{
  content:".";
  visibility:hidden;
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fl_left` div and class, then move `float: left` from h1 to div `#header`

HTML:

```
<div id="header"><h1>hello all</h1></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header
{
float: left;
width:900px;
border:dashed 1px;
margin:5px;
padding:2px;
}
#header h1
{
background-color:#666633;
color:#0033CC;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-style:oblique;
}
```

Result: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPQzD/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

CSS:

```
#header{width:900px; border:dashed 1px; margin:5px; padding:2px;}
#headerTitle{float:left; background-color:#666633; width:260px; }
#headerTitle h1{color:#0033CC; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style:oblique;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerTitle>
        <h1>hello all</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will result in the cleanest code. You have a header div, with a title div floating in this header div. This way you can still add other stuff within your header div at the right hand side (make sure to clear after that), and you can add stuff in the headerTitle box if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:-

- the header as well as it's parent div are floated left, floating the div is enough
- floated elements take up no space, that's why the header text is appearing outside the div with a border
- also, fixed typos and improved formatting

To see this in action, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YatharthROCK/6HHsX/).

## HTML Code

> **Source:** [A List Apart's article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/)

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="spacer">
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div id="header-title">
        <h1>hello all</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

We add `nbsp;` so the spacer divs aren't empty.

## CSS Code

> **Documentation:** [W3Schools CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

```css
#header {
    width:900px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:2px;

    border:dashed 1px; }

#header #header-title {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:260px; }

#header #header-title h1 {
    float:left;

    background-color:#666633;
    color:#0033CC;

    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style:oblique; }

#header .spacer {
    clear: both; }​
```

The `clear: both;` style causes no floated items to appear to either side, so the they come *around* the header rather than just go below them.